# CRM 2013: Change width of Views drop down list

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

In CRM dynamics 2013 I have few views names large enough not completely visible in the drop down box of Views.is it possible to change the widht of drop down list either using any plugin or any other option?

Comment: No. No supported way to do this that I am aware of.

Comment: I don't think there is any supported way of doing, I would suggest you to keep the names as much short you can :)

Comment: Thanks AdamV and Scorpion